# Rounding integers to nearest ten or hundred in C

Tags: c, rounding

I'm trying to think of a function in C that would satisfy the following conditions:

- It accepts an integer greater than 0 as an argument;
- It rounds that integer up to the nearest value so that only the first
  digit is not a zero

For example:

> 53 comes out as 60..
>
> 197 comes out as 200..
>
> 4937 comes out as 5000..

Is there a way to do this so that the requirement is satisfied regardless of the number of trailing zeroes?

For example, I understand how I could do it in any individual case. `divide 53 by 10 then ceil(), multiply by 10,` but I would like one that can handle any value.

Opinions? Ideas?

Comment: parse the int as string, divide the int by 10 * (string length minus 1), ceil it and multiply by your divider. Will that work?

Comment: I actually meant power, not multiplication, but I'll vote for the log solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unnecessary to convert the number to a string and back. You can do this using basic modulo arithmetic and multiplication and division.

Here's a pure numeric solution, hopefully somewhat more efficient in terms of running time:

```
int round_up_to_max_pow10(int n)
{
    int tmp = n;
    int i = 0;
    while ((tmp /= 10) >= 10) {
        i++;
    }

    if (n % (int)(pow(10, i + 1) + 0.5)) {
        tmp++;
    }

    for (; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp *= 10;
    }

    return tmp;
}

printf("Original: %d; rounded: %d\n", 4937, round_up_to_max_pow10(4937));
```

Comment: +1 Agreed! Converting to/from a string is expensive and kludgy. It's a math problem and should be treated as such.

Comment: This rounds 2445 into 3000.

Comment: @Guffa Yes, as it's expected.

Comment: @Guffa - OP unfortunately uses "round" as synonymous with "ceiling". The latter appears to be OP's intent.

Comment: @Guffa As OP says: "It rounds that integer **up** to the nearest value so that only the first digit is not a zero".

Comment: It would be good to express the code as a function as requested in the question perhaps.

Comment: This code does not work if the last element is 0. For example 4930 should produce 5000 not 4000.

Comment: @H2CO3 Technically you can combine the two loops. I erred and erred myself until I came to a similar solution down below.

Answer (score 20):

Avoid string conversions and loops:

```
int num = ... // your number
int len = log10(num);
float div = pow(10, len);
int rounded = ceil(num / div) * div;
```

Answer (score 3):

Logarithms are quite helpful here to provide a constant-time answer to the "how many zeros does this have?"

```
floor(log10(x))= z //the number of zeros
```

will take the logarithm base 10 and give you the number of zeros that will be in x.

You can then use the C occasional idiom

(A+B-1)/B

to quickly find the ceiling of A/B, which results in the correct leading digit in this way:

```
zeros = exp10(1,z);
((x+zeros-1)/zeros) * zeros
```

This is pseudocode but you should get the idea.  The key understanding is that logarithms are the way to mathematically determine how many digits a number has.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want round or ceil. But the behavior you show in the question suggests ceil. So I included that.

```
int my_ceil(int num)
{
    int den = 1;
    int inc = 0;

    while (num >= 10) {
        inc += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        den *= 10;
    }

    return (num + (inc > 0)) * den;
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed the code to remove ceil and other extra operations.

**EDIT 2**

Fixed for multiples of 10.

Comment: Doesn't work for some numbers. If the number is 9, the result is 10, if the number is 10, the result is 11...

Comment: @Guffa You are right, it wouldn't work for any multiples of 10. I think I fixed now.

Comment: @Guffa It was producing 10 not 180. Missed the parenthesis.

Comment: Works but needs C99 or C++ compilation due to placement of declarations.

Comment: @Clifford old habits :). Taking out the if condition should fix things. It is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Pavan:  The code was fine, I was just making a note for anyone using C compilation in Visual C++.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for pointing out anyway. I was able to remove an additional line of code because I looked back at it.

Answer (score 1):

By Cocoa APIs:

```
int number=9435;
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];
long length=[string length];    
NSString *roundedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",([[string substringToIndex:1]intValue]+1)];
while (--length>0) {
    roundedString=[roundedString stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
}
int roundedNumber=[roundedString intValue];
NSLog(@"%d,   %d",number,roundedNumber);
```

By Typical C style, mathematically:

```
int i=8517;

int temp=i;
int len,msb;

for (len=0; temp>0; len++) {
    msb=temp;
    temp/=10;
}
msb++;
int multiplier=1;
for (int i=1; i<len; i++) {
    multiplier*=10;
}
 NSLog(@"Rounded : %d",msb*multiplier);
```

Comment: I saw dozens of answers, and even I can solve this junior level school problem, I got eager to solve this... howver using few cocoa API this could be solved much easily.... :D

Comment: Its tooo late, but added one more way using cocoa strings

Comment: I don't think that is a good advert for Cocoa or Objective-C ;-)  Unreadable. And the question is tagged C.

Comment: @Clifford: He has edited the question, erlier it was tagged ios, cocoa, obj-c.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the number to string.  Get the length of the string.

Then:

```
// pseudo code:
divisor = pow(10, len of number string)
answer = ceil (number/divisor) * divisor;
```

Comment: The syntax isn't ok but it expresses the concept. +1.

Comment: Mathematically the number of decimal digits is `floor(log10(n) + 1))` or more simply `(int)(log10(m) + 1)` - no need for string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the first character of the input number, add 1, then append zeros.

```
    Dim Input = "23568"
    Dim roundUp = Left(Input, 1) + 1

    For x = 1 To Len(Input) - 1
        roundUp &= "0"
    Next
```

In VB, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This is tagged a C, not VB.

Comment: Hence why I wrote "In VB, but hopefully you get the idea."  The concept still applies.

Comment: If the input were 200, the output will be 300 when it should be 200.

Answer (score 0):

No loops.

```
#include <math.h>
unsigned roundToNextExp10( unsigned a )
{
    int d = a ;
    if( a >= 10 )
    {
        int m ;
        d-- ;
        m = (int)pow( 10, ((int)log10(d)) ) ;
        d = (int)((d / m) + 1) * m ;
    }        
    return d ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the number by ten until there is only one digit left, then multiply it back to size:

```
int n = 4937;

int m = 1;
while (n >= 10) {
  n = (n + 9) / 10;
  m *= 10;
}
n *= m;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
static int
rnd_up(int val)
{
    double e, r;

    e = exp10(trunc(log10((double)val)));
    r = round(((double)val / e) + 0.5);

    return(r * e);
}
```

Comment: May be worth noting that `exp10(n)` is a GNU library extension equivalent to `pow(10,n)`

Comment: `trunc()` and `round()` are not standard either

Comment: Compiled on standard linux using _GNU_SOURCE and math.h. I did not see a request to solve the problem with any particular subset of that.

Comment: Indeed, I just made the point for anyone to whom it is important.  In this case I tested many of the more rational looking solutions posted, but yours I could not test with VC++. I would take the lack of a target specification as implying a need for the widest possible widest possible applicability rather than a mandate to narrow the solution.

Comment: My goal was not to solve the actual problem of compiling the code, which is why I did not supply the whole program, though I had one. My goal was to show that the math is rather simple, and that it could be done for example on a standard Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/* Round up a number                               */
/* (Negative numbers go DOWN)                      */
/* 34 -> 40                                        */
/* -34 -> -40                                      */
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
int round_up_10(int num) 
{
    int sign = 1;
    int tens = 1;

    if (num < 0)
    {
        num = (-1) * num;
        sign = -1;
    }
    num = (num + 9) / 10;
    num = num * 10;

    return sign * num;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/* Round down a number                             */
/* (Negative numbers go UP)                        */
/* 34 -> 30                                        */
/* -34 -> -30                                      */
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
int round_down_10(int num)   
{
    int sign = 1;
    int tens = 1;

    if (num < 0)
    {
        num = (-1) * num;
        sign = -1;
    }
    num = num / 10;
    num = num * 10;

    return sign * num;
}

main()
{
    printf("round_down_10(25450)= %d\n", round_down_10(25450));
    printf("round_down_10(-25450)= %d\n", round_down_10(-25450));
    printf("round_up_10(25450)= %d\n", round_up_10(25450));
    printf("round_up_10(-25450)= %d\n", round_up_10(-25450));

    printf("round_down_10(1347)= %d\n", round_down_10(1347));
    printf("round_down_10(-1347)= %d\n", round_down_10(-1347));
    printf("round_up_10(1347)= %d\n", round_up_10(1347));
    printf("round_up_10(-1347)= %d\n", round_up_10(-1347));

    printf("round_down_10(34)= %d\n", round_down_10(34));
    printf("round_down_10(-34)= %d\n", round_down_10(-34));
    printf("round_up_10(34)= %d\n", round_up_10(34));
    printf("round_up_10(-34)= %d\n", round_up_10(-34));
}
    /*
    The outout:
    round_down_10(25450)= 25450
    round_down_10(-25450)= -25450
    round_up_10(25450)= 25450
    round_up_10(-25450)= -25450
    round_down_10(1347)= 1340
    round_down_10(-1347)= -1340
    round_up_10(1347)= 1350
    round_up_10(-1347)= -1350
    round_down_10(34)= 30
    round_down_10(-34)= -30
    round_up_10(34)= 40
    round_up_10(-34)= -40
    */
```

Comment: This does not appear to satisfy the conditions put forth in the OP - "Is there a way to do this so that the requirement is satisfied regardless of the number of trailing zeroes?"

Answer (score -3):

Some expert advice you get here... To round a number *i* up to nearest 10:

```
if (i%10)
   i += 10 - i%10;
```

Similarly for 100s, 1000s, etc.