# Rounding big numbers to nearest hundred, float is losing value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to round big numbers to the nearest 1 hundred, by dividing by 100, rounding and then multiplying by 100.

However, the big number values are losing value when converting to floats.

This is the problem part:

```
int bigInt = 99222049;
float bigFloat = bigInt / 100.0;
NSLog(@"%d     %f", bigInt, bigFloat);
```

Output:

```
99222049     992220.500000
```

Would like it to be:

```
99222049     992220.49
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question! Would be grateful for advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your float to a double.

```
int bigInt = 99222049;
double bigFloat = bigInt / 100.0;
NSLog(@"%u     %f", bigInt, bigFloat);
```

Outputs:

```
99222049     992220.490000
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That seems to work great! If the number is LARGE I will use a 'double', else I will use normal float. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your basic problem is float rounding. You cannot express arbitrary decimal fractions as floats (or doubles). In binary, [1/10 is 0.00011001100110011...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.1%20to%20binary) It never terminates, just like 1/3 is 0.33333... in decimal. So you need to do your work in base 10, not base 2, if you want your results to round nicely in base 10. There are two approaches in Cocoa:

You can do your work purely with integer math, no floating point. See [Rounding integers to nearest ten or hundred in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344833/rounding-integers-to-nearest-ten-or-hundred-in-c) for an example of how to do this.

Alternately, since this is ObjC, you can use `NSDecimalNumber`, which will allow you to perform all your math in base 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation Rob, and very useful information. I will use Peter's solution below for a quick fix though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and the output should show as you desire. I changed the float to a double and .2 before f to show only 2 decimal places.

```
int bigInt = 99222049;
double bigFloat = bigInt / 100.0;
NSLog(@"%d     %.2f", bigInt, bigFloat);
```

This is what shows in console

```
99222049     992220.49
```

I hope this helps, cheers, Jim.