# Round a value down to the nearest hundred or thousand by a given value?

Tags: swift

I'm writing a func to populate the top value of the Y axis of a chart by a given value.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this: If the given value is between 100 - 199 then choose 100, if it is between 200 and 299 then chose 200, and so on even with biggest numbers like if it between 10.000 and 10.999 then choose 10.000.

I tried with the following code but I quickly realized how messy it will end up... there must be a better way.

```
private func chartTopValueFromGivenValue(givenValue: Float) -> Float {
    let startNumber:Float = 100.0
    let endNumber:Float = 199.9
    let numberRange = startNumber...endNumber
    
    if numberRange.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 100.0
    }
    
    let startNumber2:Float = 200.0
    let endNumber2:Float = 299.9
    let numberRange2 = startNumber2...endNumber2
    
    if numberRange2.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 200.0
    }
    
    let startNumber3:Float = 300.0
    let endNumber3:Float = 399.9
    let numberRange3 = startNumber3...endNumber3
    
    if numberRange3.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 300.0
    }
    
    let startNumber4:Float = 300.0
    let endNumber4:Float = 499.9
    let numberRange4 = startNumber4...endNumber4
    
    if numberRange4.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 400.0
    }
    
    let startNumber5:Float = 500.0
    let endNumber5:Float = 599.9
    let numberRange5 = startNumber5...endNumber5
    
    if numberRange5.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 500.0
    }
    
    let startNumber6:Float = 600.0
    let endNumber6:Float = 699.9
    let numberRange6 = startNumber6...endNumber6
    
    if numberRange6.contains(barsValueMax) {
        return 600.0
    }
    
    return 0.0
}
```

Comment: With your logic `199.90` returns 0? Is this intended?

Comment: Hi @vadian, no it should return 100.0, updating the snippet.

Comment: You can devide the value by 100, get the integer value floored and multiply it by 100 back? `floor(value / 100.0) * 100.0`, but for 19999 to get 10000, you need to adapt the logic, indeed... What's the limit/logic here, per "ten"?

Comment: When using `switch` you can make each `case` a range like `case 0.0...1000.0:` which could be helpful here to avoid all those `if` clauses

Comment: Inspired with https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345003/1801544 `let div = powf(10, Float(Int(log10(value)))); return floorf(value / div) * div` might do the trick, but more cases are needed to see if it's correct according to your needs.

Comment: Hi guys I think I did it with the code I'll post

Comment: @Larme, that's a useful answer; you should post it. (Though I'd drop the Float; `pow(10, floor(log10(value)))` keeps it in Double with fewer conversions.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your rounding conditions, this might do the trick:

```
func roundValues(_ value: Float) -> Float {
    let div = pow(10, floor(log10(value)))
    return floorf(value / div) * div
}
```

Testing:

```
let values: [Float] = [100.0, 101.1, 199.9, 200.0, 2001, 1999.4, 49000.0, 55000.0]

values.forEach {
    print("For: \($0) got: \(roundValues($0))")
}
```

With output:

```
$>For: 100.0 got: 100.0
$>For: 101.1 got: 100.0
$>For: 199.9 got: 100.0
$>For: 200.0 got: 200.0
$>For: 2001.0 got: 2000.0
$>For: 1999.4 got: 1000.0
$>For: 49000.0 got: 40000.0
$>For: 55000.0 got: 50000.0
```

This code is inspired by [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) on a similar [C question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345003/1801544), and optimized by [@Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) in from my first suggestion/conversion in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237745/round-a-value-down-to-the-nearest-hundred-or-thousand-by-a-given-value#comment136170129_77237745).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions I could achieve what I wanted

```
switch barsValueMax {
case 1_000_000_000...:
     return floor(barsValueMax / 1000000000.0) * 1000000000.0
    
case 1_000_000...:
     return floor(barsValueMax / 1000000.0) * 1000000.0

case 1_000...:
     return floor(barsValueMax / 1000.0) * 1000.0
case 0...:
    return floor(barsValueMax / 100.0) * 100.0
default:
    return 0.0
}
```